# How to get all parameters used by the AWS account without providing a parameter name?

Tags: amazon-web-services

When I need to fetch all of the secrets that are stored by `AWS Secrets Manager` in the AWS account I'm calling `listSecrets` passing `ListSecretsRequest` as an argument.

And now I'm looking for a similar method in `AWS Systems Manager` to get all parameters stored in the AWS account.
I have found a `getParameterHistory` method in the API [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_GetParameterHistory.html) but the description looks confusing. The Request syntax states that there is a **required** `Name` parameter (The name of a parameter you want to query). But I need to get all parameters without providing a certain name.

I'm getting the following error when calling the method: `AWSSimpleSystemsManagementException: 1 validation error detected: Value null at 'name' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null (Service: AWSSimpleSystemsManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 0caa3be7-9d85-4671-9515-fdcc45c641d6)`

At the same time the API provides a `getParameter` method that allows to `Get information about a parameter by using the parameter name`.

What is the correct way to get all parameters used by the AWS account via `AWS Secrets Manager` similar to the `AWS Secrets Manager`'s `listSecrets` method without having to provide a parameter name?

Answer (score 1):

Call [describeParameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simplesystemsmanagement/AWSSimpleSystemsManagement.html#describeParameters-com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.model.DescribeParametersRequest-)(describeParametersRequest)

Comment: According to the documentation `describeParameters(describeParametersRequest) ` is used to `Get information about a parameter.` But what I need is to get all parameters stored in the AWS account. Am I correct that the method you suggested will allow to get all parameters?

Comment: Did you try to call it without filters?